# Why is the force that does the work, when calculating the electric potential energy, symmetric to the electric force?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, work, potential-energy

"The electrical potential at a point is the work per unit charge required to move the charge to that point (*r*) from another point which has been assigned a potential of zero ($r_{0}$)". This work is calculated as follows:
$$W = \int_{r_{0}}^{r}-\vec{F_{e}}\cdot d\vec{r}$$
Why does the force we use to calculate the work is the symmetrical of the electrical force? It seems obvious to me that the force responsible for bringing the particle from $r_{0}$ to $r$ must have the opposite direction, what is not so obvious for me is why it has the same size as the electric force.

If I try to push a heavy wardrobe, I'm indeed applying a force to it, but as long as I don't surpass the friction force, the wardrobe doesn't move and therefore I'm not doing any work on the wardrobe. My doubt is the same in this situation. If the force that supposedly is responsible for doing work in the particle has the same magnitude as the electric force being exerted on it, the particle can't possibly move from there in the first place, just like the picture illustrates (EF stands for electrical force):
[image]

I get that this is the minimum intensity the force must have that contraries the electric field on that point, but it is not enough to make the particle keep moving to the next point. So why is the work defined like that? What am I getting wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help, and I'm sorry if I was a little confusing in the beginning.

Comment: Perhaps it's just me, but I must confess I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @BobD how do you define electric potential?

Comment: Defining potential to be int  negative e.dl doesn't mean a force opposing the direction of the E field actually exists.

Comment: I'm squarely with Bob D here. Voted to close.

Comment: The force that does the work is Eq,  potential is not defined as the work done by the force on the object. -E is not an actual force

Comment: @arpg.  The electrical potential at a point is the work per unit charge required to move the charge to that point from another point which has been assigned a potential of zero (technically a completely arbitrary but generally logical decision)

Comment: @BobD yes, my question is, how do you know the amount of work you have to do to move the charge?

Comment: I edited my question, please be kind enough to tell me if it's still confusing the way I expressed myself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why when change in kinetic energy equals to zero the work done by two opposite forces is equal even if displacement takes place?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/505774/why-when-change-in-kinetic-energy-equals-to-zero-the-work-done-by-two-opposite-f)

Answer (score 2):

If the force used to move the charge was not exactly the negative of the electrical force then there would be (by definition) an unbalanced force which would then cause the charge to accelerate.  This is something that we are conceptually trying to avoid because that moving charge then acquires kinetic energy and also the physics becomes more complicated once there are moving charges involved.  So instead we consider moving the charge quasi-statically which is to say moving arbitrarily slowly.  This means the unbalanced forces required to start it moving and stop it are thus arbitrarily small.  This is why we can consider the force moving the charge to be equal to the negative of the electrical force.

Answer (score 1):

In order to increase the potential of a positive charge an external agent must exert a force on the charge in a direction opposite the electric field.

Assuming the charge begins at rest, clearly the magnitude of the external force must be greater than the magnitude of the force exerted by the field in order to accelerate the charge to give it a velocity. Then the external force need only match the force of the field to keep the charge moving at constant velocity.

Then, prior to reaching the end point, the external force must be less than the force of the electric field so that the charge decelerates and brought to rest at the end point. In this manner the change in kinetic energy is zero and all the work done by the external agent becomes electrical potential energy.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Let a positive small charge free to move at some distance from a big positive charge. It will be repelled by the E-field. The work done between the initial point and the second is:

$$w = \int_{r_1}^{r_2} \mathbf{F_e.dr} = \int_{r_1}^{r_2} \frac{kQq}{r^2}dr = -(\frac{kQq}{r_2} - \frac{kQq}{r_1})$$

If we let $r_2 = r_0 = \infty$, it corresponds to zero potential, remaining:

$$w = \frac{kQq}{r_1}$$

which is positive. So if we invert the limits of integration, it necessary to put a minus sign:

$$w = \int_{r_0}^{r_1} -\mathbf{F_e.dr}$$

Comment: Although it doesn't satisfy me completely, I think I can live with this answer.